# Options for executing API functions in a new AppDomain

Tags: c#

I want to call an API running inside a new AppDomain (FWIW in the asp.net MVC framework).  I discovered a few options for executing code within the AppDomain.  I'm not happy with the verbosity of the solutions I've seen thus far:

I discovered:

**assembly execution**:

```
appDomain.ExecuteAssembly("SOMEPATH.exe");
```

Firing off an executeable is not a good way to make API calls.  I imagine the need to pass various parameters to `Main()` that represent each public method in the API.

**Reflection:**

```
ObjectHandle handle = appDomain.CreateInstance("someassembly.dll", "someType");
A a = (A) handle.Unwrap();
a.SomeField = "foo";
```

This strikes me as a superior solution for an API.  However, I'm not a big fan of Reflection due to the complex setup and the potential for performance overhead.

Is there a means to loadup an appdomain in a new thread so I can fire off methods without going through these hoops?  In other words some means to effectively:

```
Thread.Start("useThisAppdomain", 
  //do work.
  className.M();//run in new appdomain
);
```

or the like?

Comment: Could you please explain your high level goal? I would not recommend to deal with AppDomains unless you have very solid arguments. They are much harder to deal with and provide no significant benefits. (The only one is `AppDomain.Unload`)

Comment: @Andrey - The reason I am introducing appdomains is because I need to heavily restrict the security and analyze code launched within that context.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey, it is still not clear what your actual requirements are... but see if my answer makes it more clear what is missing from the question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are concerned about adding security restrictions on code executed in other domain it most likely means that you can't also let any of that code to run in original domain (where it will not be restricted) - so you are most likely have usual "do not leak types cross AppDomain boundary" requirement. Clearly separating code that runs in one AppDomain from another will minimize need for creating objects in other domains. I many cases single "code runner" class may be enough to schedule work in other domain and return results. You should be able to write code for each side normally (assuming that you don't need to load unknown assemblies).

Original suggestion (before security requirement):

Assuming you are not concerned about not leaking types across App domain boundary (which is most common use of AppDomains - make some assemblies "unloadable" by constraining them to one new AppDomain).

You should be able to write helper methods that allow strongly typed creation of objects in other domain - normally such code is not possible due to "leaking" types from new domain down to original domain (and thus loading other assemblies into original domain and preventing unload/updates to assembly).

Note: thread and AppDomains are unrelated concepts - same thread can have code from multiple domains on one stack. There is no built in way to restrict a thread to "run in single app domain".

Comment: Can you explain "You should be able to write code for each side normally"?  The point of my question is along the lines of "I wish I could write code as I normally do inside a new appdomain".  If I understand you correctly, you are saying I can.  Can you give a code sample as to how exactly I switch appdomains and then write code that runs in the new appdomain "as I normally do"?

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey, the only place where you need to write special code is when you are crossing AppDomain boundary first time - if you move all interesting code to be run in single AppDomain most of the code would look normal. I.e. have class that have single method "run all code and return true/false" and just instantiate that class and run that single method cross app domain (I'll try to add sample eventually).

Comment: Oh I see.  The complexity is in the fact that I am to cross the appdomains each time I make an API call.  In other words, the API is effectively the boundary between appdomains.  So then I will go with your original suggestion to add a helper method to hide the ugly implementation details of running back and forth between appdomains.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey, OK. Just to reiterate - make sure you understand what happens when you get results back to original domain - if you are not careful you can "leak" object/type from assembly you are calling back into your main domain - which may be an issue if you are trying to restrict what that assembly can do as some of that assembly run code in your original domain.